# Genesis 3:22 as a reference to Yona?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, parashat-bereishit

I was told that there is a midrash that learns [Genesis 3:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0103.htm#22) as a reference to the navi (prophet) [Yona ben Amitai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah), but cannot find the source. Do you know where it is?

Comment: avi, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your question. Any information you can [edit into the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/19020/edit) that might help people find the _midrash_ in question, such as where you heard of it, might help you get a better answer. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1886/avi), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are referring to Bereishit Rabbah 21:5.

There, Rav Papus understands the verse to be suggesting that people sought to become like one of the ministering angels. Rabbi Akiva disagrees, and interprets the verse as indicating that they chose the path of death instead of the path of life. Rabbi Yehuda bar Simon understands it to mean that they sought to become like God himself, while the other rabbis understand it to imply that they sought to become like Gabriel. Finally, Reish Laqish suggests that before this point they had been like Jonah, while Rabbi Berekhiah believes that they had been like Elijah.

A number of things about the passage are difficult to interpret, not least among which is how Reish Laqish connects the text to Jonah in the first place. The Maharzav (Rabbi Ze'ev Wolf Einhorn) and the Rashash (Rabbi Shmuel Strashun) connect the word אחד in the verse (כאחד ממנו) with the same word in 2 Kings 9:1, which both Rashi and Radaq connect with Jonah (based on Seder Olam Rabbah §18).

In any case, the language used by Reish Laqish is as follows:

> ריש לקיש אמר כיונה מה זה בורח משליחותו של מקום שנאמר ויקם יונה לברח
>   תרשישה מלפני ה, אף זה בורח מלקים צווי המקום, מה זה לא לן בכבודו אף זה
>   לא לן כבודו עמו
>
> Reish Laqish said [that they were] like Jonah. Just as this one ran
>   away from the mission of God - as it says, "Jonah arose and fled from
>   before God to Tarshish" - so too this one [ie: these people] escaped
>   from observing the commandments of God. Just as this one lost all
>   honour [lit. "did not sleep with his honour"], so too did this one
>   [ie: these people] lose all honour.
>
> - Bereishit Rabbah 21:5

(The notion that Jonah lost all honour is explained by the Maharzav *in situ*, in reference to a passage at the beginning of the Mekhilta.)